# creating an n tier .net application

Tags: n-tier-architecture

I have three projects which are class libraries. One is the Biz layer with the entity classes in it, another is the Data STore Layer with the DAL classes in it and finally both these projects hve been referenced in the controller project which co-ordinated the entire use case. The controller class lib project is referenced in the windows form project.

I have created interfaces that are implemented by the Entity classes the Biz tier. I am using these interfaces in the winform project to store a reference of the entity class objects that are returned by various functions into the windows form. I am doing this since i do not want to directly reference the Biz logic layed in the windows form project and I need a loosely coupled solution. Only the Contoller classlib is referenced in the windows form. However when i use the interface to store the object reference of the entity class in the windows form project it gives a compile error asking me to reference the Biz logic layer project. The interface has the same declarations as the actual entity class.

How should i solve this problem.